# Accessing Microsoft Graph Rest Services in Java using Web App Credentials in Azure Portal

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access the following url via Microsoft Graph Api :-
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
I have used the code given below found on stackoverflow which should ideally give me JSON. But I am getting exception while running the code :-

```
try {
            String url_str = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";
            String access_token = getAccessToken();

            url = new URL(url_str);
            con = ( HttpURLConnection )url.openConnection();
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setUseCaches(false);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", access_token);
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
            con.connect();

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( con.getInputStream() ));
            String str = null;
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                str += line;
            }
            System.out.println(str);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am getting valid access token. But I am getting following exception:-

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.controller.MicrosoftGraphController.getUserInfo(MicrosoftGraphController.java:50)
    at com.controller.MicrosoftGraphController.main(MicrosoftGraphController.java:82)
```

I tried searching but haven't found anything related to this particular issue. Any Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.io.FileNotFoundException when I use Get Method in an HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843211/java-io-filenotfoundexception-when-i-use-get-method-in-an-http-request)

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I am getting 404 response but still I am not able to figure out changes to be made in code to access the resource on server.

Comment: Can you add a capture of the HTTP traffic for this call? There should be a more detailed response than a simple `404` over the wire.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I am just debugging in eclipse... so i am not able to get any detailed response besides what I have mentioned.

Comment: You can use a tool like Fiddler or Wireshark to capture the traffic. Without seeing what is happening under the hood, it will be next to impossible to diagnose.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I solved my issue. I just wanted to ask you is there any other way better than what I am doing to access graph api in Java? As I need to deserialize the JSON myself rather than it being mapped to the class directly.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to be:

```
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
```

You're using the OAuth2 protocol and it needs more than just the raw token.  Note the space character after the word "Bearer" in the code.

Take a look at [the docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks! I will post my answer and its something else that resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because the service is returning an error instead of a valid response, I believe you will have to handle this in your code manually:

```
int httpClientErrorResponseCode = 400;
InputStream response;

if (con.getResponseCode() >= httpClientErrorResponseCode) {
    response = con.getErrorStream();
} else {
    response = con.getInputStream();
}
// Stream response or handle error
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at my code. I realized as I have created web app in azure portal and I am using the app credentials to get authentication token. So the url that I was trying was related to the personal account "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me" but after trying "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" I was able to access the graph api's. Auth token has nothing to do with this.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct, it _is_ a token issue. The `/me` method works the same for both personal (MSA) and work/school accounts (AAD). What won't work however is signing in to a v1 App registered in the Azure Portal with an MSA. In order to use _both_ MSA and AAD accounts, you need to created a Converged App registration at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and use the v2 Endpoint.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Thanks!